# Durandal and jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, durandal

There is already an example of jqxGrid that is labeled "jqGrid integration with existing Durandal solution".  However, I don't have the option of using jqxGrid.

Does any one have an example of using jqGrid with durandal.  This is what I'm trying now and it is not working.

Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: attr: { href: 'animals/' + id, title: name }, text: id
Message: id is not defined;

### viewmodel.js

///

define(['durandal/app', 'jqgrid', 'kojqgrid'], function (app) {

```
var initialData = [
            { id: 1, name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
            { id: 2, name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
            { id: 3, name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
            { id: 4, name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
            { id: 5, name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
            { id: 6, name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
            { id: 7, name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
];

var ctor = function () {

    this.animals = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.disabled = ko.observable(false);

    this.activate = function () {
        this.animals(initialData);
        return true;
    }
};

//Note: This module exports a function. That means that you, the developer, can create multiple instances.
//This pattern is also recognized by Durandal so that it can create instances on demand.

return ctor;
```

});

**View
-------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
<h3>Customers</h3>

<table id="animals" data-bind="grid: { data: animals }" >
    <caption>Amazing Animals</caption>
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th data-field="actions" style="width:27px;"></th>
            <th data-field="name" width="150px">Item Name</th> 
            <th data-field="sales">Sales Count</th> 
            <th data-field="price">Price</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-field="actions">
                <a class="grid-edit" data-bind="attr: { href: 'animals/' + id, title: name }, text: id"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting id is undefined is because the ctor function does not expose id or name attribute but the animals observableArray. In your view you need to loop over the animals obserbavbleArray to get access to id and name attribute for each animal. Try the following code:

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach:animals'>
    <tr>
        <td data-field="actions">
            <a class="grid-edit" data-bind="attr: { href: 'animals/' + id, title: name }, text: id"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, however, in this particular example this solution doesn't solve my problem.  Maybe I didn't explain it well enough.  The problem is that jqGrid knockout binding doesn't seem to be working with durandal.

The code above comes directly from the sample code at:

https://github.com/CraigCav/Knockout-jqGridBinding

This doesn't seem to work through durandal even though it is using knockout.

Comment: @JohnnyFever This actually has nothing to do with Durandal, per se.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `activate` handler on the prototype:

```
ctor.prototype.activate = function () {...}
```

Durandal likely cannot find your `activate` handler and, therefore, never initializes the data.

Also, I can only assume that the jqGrid binding is looking at the table definition and harvesting from the DOM what it needs to build a proper binding.  The reason I say that is that, strictly speaking, @nimrig is right: there needs to be a `foreach` somewhere.  It must be that the jqGrid is building that `foreach`.